# Xerox network accounting (JBA) C70 sending accounting users

Tags: php, printers

I am trying to send a list of users to the Xerox for network accounting purposes.

I successfully do this with 2 Xerox models (XEROX WorkCentre 7556 and XEROX WorkCentre 7830), following sudo code in PHP:

```
function SendUsersToXerox($ip,$users)
{
    $url="{$ip}/acct/set_auth";
    $auth='account:jbaserve';
    $post="+aaav1.0\n+purge\n";

    foreach ($users as $u)
    {
        $post.="+u\"{$u->login}\"\"{$u->code}\"\n";
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'EQ Device Control Engine');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$auth");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/xrx-acct-data']);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
//  echo "HTTP CODE: {$httpcode}<br/>";
//  echo $data;
}
```

This code works perfectly on the above named Xerox's but fails on the C70 with a 401 error and the following message:

```
Invalid accounting authentication version
```

Network accounting is enabled on the device, and I can collect all jobs from the printer at the URL acct/get_acct

If I pass in bad post data I get a different error message:

```
HTTP Return 400
The Request had invalid syntax
```

I can't find any references to JBA or Network Accounting anywhere and am not sure how to find out if the format has changed on set_auth or if it's version difference that needs to be set.

I know there are differences in the get_acct output that does point to a different version of the accounting.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple.
Everything is correct except the following:

```
$post="+aaav1.0+\n+purge\n";
```

The plus(+) after the v1.0 allows the users to be uploaded for accounting.